# Stuck at grub 2.04 screen

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, lenovo, windows-10

I installed ubuntu 20.04, via USB stick (DISK C), into a NVME drive connected via USB (NVME case, DISK B).

It worked like a charm. My disk A (Windows 10) was untouched.

I set up a root file, boot as UEFI into DISK B, swap file, and all the rest of the NVME to /home

Then began my saga. When I try to boot from the drive, even tought my bios does recognize the Ubuntu installation, grub is stuck at the 2.04 screen ([GRUB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G31rJ.png))

Then, to check, I changed the BIOS to legacy mode, UEFI first. This made things worse: The bios started freezing (literally), I couldn't login in windows 10 and when booting to Ubuntu, same Grub page but it froze and did not respond.

But, after two or three restarts, Grub options showed up and I could boot to both windows 10 and ubuntu. Upon restarting, got the same aberrant behavior.

To recover my BIOS, i had to physically uninstall both DISK A and DISK B, change BIOS to UEFI, then I got back Windows 10.

Still, I can't access my Ubuntu installation on the USB NVME drive (DISK B).
My notebook is a Y70-70

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, your print-screen shows a virtualbox window with Arch linux running in it - how does that relate to dual-booting ubuntu with Windows ?

Comment: That exactly the message that I was getting. This was just an example, because I couldn't screenshot it. No login into ubuntu, just that page